# Finding normalization constant of a wave function with definite momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I try to read Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics but I stuck at this point,

$$\delta(x^{'}-x^{''})=|N|^{2}\int dp^{'}\exp\Biggl({ip^{'}(x^{'}-x^{''})2\pi\over h}\Biggr)$$

This is an expression for finding normalization constant ,After this step he shows

$$|N|^{2}\int dp^{'}\exp\Biggl({ip^{'}(x^{'}-x^{''})2\pi\over h}\Biggr)
   =h|N|^{2}\delta(x^{'}-x^{''})$$

I don't get this step , Please help me to move more

Comment: Check Dirac Delta definition

Answer (score 1):

The first equation expresses the orthogonality property of the momentum eigenfunctions.
There is the well-known formula for the Dirac delta function:
$$
\delta(x) = \frac1{2\pi}\int\! dk\  e^{ikx}.
$$
If you will make the change of variable
$$
p' = k\frac{h}{2\pi}
$$
in the integral, then you would obtain your second formula. Together two formulas give
$$
|N|^2 = \frac1{h}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your precious help Gec @ Gec

Comment: @Robin Raj , Why wouldn't you accept the answer, then?